# error when i run an apps with Trigger.io

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, trigger.io, forge

when i try to use the module request, the  forge.request.ajax returns an error here's the code :

```
 $(document).on("pagecreate", "#add_menu", function () {
        forge.logging.info("page created");
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#scanQRCode', function () {
        forge.logging.info("clickss");
        forge.request.ajax({
             type: "POST",
         url: getLink(),
         data:'data',
             success: function (data) {
                forge.logging.info("ok");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                forge.logging.error("[getresponse ] " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });
```

the error on Local Toolkit :

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'e' [null] is not an object. -- From line 2 of content://io.trigger.forge1e218252567411e3a2d612313b0234c0/forge/all.js
```

Comment: How about passing `e` to your  click callback function?

Comment: same error,  but when i added some code instead of comment
i get this error :

SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string -- From line 4 of content://io.trigger.forge1e218252567411e3a2d612313b0234c0/src/assets/js/menu/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: i think that the code is running before the jquery is loaded..

Comment: i found the solution, the problem isn't on forge but in call WS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your solution was, but looking at your code you haven't passed a `url` parameter through to `forge.request.ajax` which is required.

Comment: the problem was at the back of the WS, it was not well written